# Face Attributes with Text Properties

Tags: faces, text-properties

Is there any way to have all text with a specific face also receive a specific text-property?

As a concrete example, there is a special text-property, `line-prefix`, that I would like to use for some face, however this is a *text property*, not a *face attribute*, so adding such a attribute to the face doesn't appear to do anything, e.g.:

```
(set-face-attribute 'dap-ui-verified-breakpoint-face nil
                     :weight 'bold
                     :slant 'italic
                     :line-prefix "*")
```

Comment: The answer depends on how the face was originally inserted into the buffer in the first place. Was this done using font-lock? If so, is it a package that you write yourself, or does it come from a third party?

Comment: Unfortunately, the faces are not controlled by myself but are inserted by a third-party package ([dap-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode) to be specific)

Comment: I don't know the package, but it looks like things like this is done in `dap-ui--make-overlay`. If you run under a window system, it defined fringe symbols. You could probably modify it for terminal use (which I guess is your reason for using `line-prefix`). How knows, maybe you can suggest this as a possible enhancement to the package.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running this inside a terminal, which doesn't support margins/fringes, and consequently doesn't display any breakpoint indications by default, hence the effort and questions. Although that is an interesting find, maybe I'll spend some time to change that function to allow arbitrary text properties and send them a pull-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add nonexistent face properties to faces.  (You can add any properties you like to face symbols, but that's not the same thing.)

But you can add nonexistent (and existent) *text properties* to all (or to just some) *occurrences of buffer text that **has** a given face*.

You can do that easily with library [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el). You can do it using command **`isearchp-add-prop-to-other-prop-zones`**:

> **`isearchp-add-prop-to-other-prop-zones`** is an interactive compiled Lisp
> function in [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el).
>
> `(isearchp-add-prop-to-other-prop-zones PROP-TO-ADD VALUE-TO-ADD PROP-TO-FIND VALUE-TO-FIND TYPE-TO-FIND &optional START END MSGP)`
>
> **Add text property to text that has another property**, from `START` to `END`.
>
> `PROP-TO-ADD` and `VALUE-TO-ADD` are the property to add and its value.
>
> `PROP-TO-FIND`, `VALUE-TO-FIND`, and `TYPE-TO-FIND` are the existing
> property, its value, and its type (symbol `text` or `overlay`).
>
> `START` and `END` are the buffer limits, or the region limits if active.
>
> Interactively, you are prompted for the required arguments.
>
> Returns non-`nil` if the property was added, `nil` if not.

See also [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus).

Comment: Suspected as much, and that's a good solution/workaround. Now I just need to find an appropriate hook where this can be called!